# issues in docker-compose when running up, cannot find localhost and services starting in wrong order

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having a couple of issues running docker-compose.
`docker-compose up` already works in starting the webservice (stuffapi) and I can hit the endpoint with `http://localhost:8080/stuff`.

1. I have a small go app that I would like to run with docker-compose using a local dockerfile.  The dockerfile when built locally cannot call the stuffapi service on localhost.  I have tried using the service name, ie `http://stuffapi:8080` however this gives an error `lookup stuffapi on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host`.
   I'm guessing this has something to do with the default network setup?
2. After the stuffapi service has started I would like my service to be built (stuffsdk in dockerfile), then execute a command to run the go app which calls the stuff (web) service.  docker-compose tries to build the local dockerfile first but when it runs its last command `RUN ./main`, it fails as the stuffapi hasn't been started first.  In my service I have a `depends_on` the stuffapi service so I thought that would start first?

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  stuffapi:
    image: XXX
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  stuffsdk:
    depends_on: 
      - stuffapi
    build: .
```

dockerfile:

```
From golang:1.15
RUN mkdir /stuffsdk
RUN mkdir /main
ADD ./stuffsdk /stuffsdk
ADD ./main /main
ENV BASE_URL=http://stuffapi:8080
WORKDIR /main
RUN go build
RUN ./main
```

Comment: Should these be two separate questions?  In the first part, what URL are you trying to use to call the container, from where?  In the second part, a Dockerfile can never connect to another container (even if they're in the same Compose file and one `depends_on:` the other, it still won't work) and whatever connection you need will have to be done at container startup time.  (Do you mean `CMD ./main`?)

Comment: Lets say stuffsdk is a test library.  So when stuffapi is running, I want to run 'go test' and run the tests in stuffsdk against stuffapi (using docker-compose up).  So how can stuffsdk wait for stuffapi to be up and running and then execute its tests?  Second part to that is what url does one container use to call another?  http://stuffapi:8080 does not seem to work.

Comment: I'd run `go test` from my build environment, outside Docker, and point it at the published `ports:`, most likely `http://localhost:8080`.  You cannot connect to the running container from the Dockerfile.

Comment: Yep that was working before I started trying with docker-compose.  Why can't it work out of curiosity?  A web app can call a db running in a separate container both started from docker-compose.

Comment: The build sequence isn't connected to the Docker network that Compose creates; if the build depended on or modified a database, it wouldn't have reproducible results.